# Multiple SSL enabled websites on Azure VM using load balancer

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, https, azure

I have a Virtual Machine running in Azure that is hosting several websites in IIS.
The VM has a loadbalancer in front of it, and in my DNS settings I point my A-record to the loadbalancers's IP address.

This all works fine with one website in IIS when I can set the binding IP to 'All Unassigned', but when using multiple sites, I'm stuck.

How I can I configure this, can I register multiple IP's to my Azure Loadbalancer or can I soly fix this with IIS config.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Host Headers in IIS? this will allow you to use the same IP Address and Same port to access multiple Web sites on the same Web server.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Without using host headers you can only bind one SSL enabled site to an IP address, the simplistic explanation is that when using SSL the headers are encrypted and IIS cannot inspect the request to determine where it needs to go.

Not knowing which version of IIS you're using I've included two methods below:

In IIS 7 and below there is no way to do this in the GUI, however using this super handy tool [IIS Buddy binding tool](http://www.simplygoodcode.com/2012/09/configure-iis-ssl-host-header-using-a-ui) you can easily assign mutiple HTTPS bindings / certificates on a single IP address it is also worth noting that giving your certificate a friendly name beginning with * can solve some problems.

In IIS 8 there is the option to require Server Name Indication, more information here [Add HTTP host headers in IIS 8](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/ssl-host-headers-iis-8.htm)